# How to refresh the currently connected device in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE tool and encountering an issue where it doesn't recognize newly connected devices. For example, if I open Visual Studio Code first and then connect an Android device, it seems that Visual Studio Code cannot detect the target device. I haven't found any refresh functionality, so I end up restarting Visual Studio Code every time to resolve it. Is there a better solution?